# How do I get a reference to an element of an array in D?

Tags: arrays, reference, pass-by-reference, d

I have this D-code for reading data from a file:

```
int foo (SomeStruct[] somestruct_array)
{
  // get file_handle...
  for (uint i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    file_handle.readf ("%e %e %e %e %e %e\n",
            &(somestruct_array[i].pos_x), &(somestruct_array[i].pos_y),
            &(somestruct_array[i].pos_z), &(somestruct_array[i].vel_x),
            &(somestruct_array[i].vel_y), &(somestruct_array[i].vel_z));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the lines are getting quiet long and I keep repeating `somestruct_array[i]`. It's not a big deal, but I tried to shorten that and write:

```
int foo (SomeStruct[] somestruct_array)
{
  // get file_handle...
  for (uint i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    auto elem = somestruct_array[i];
    file_handle.readf ("%e %e %e %e %e %e\n",
            &(elem.pos_x), &(elem.pos_y),
            &(elem.pos_z), &(elem.vel_x),
            &(elem.vel_y), &(elem.vel_z));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This results in all the element members being `nan`.

So: Is it possible to get a reference to array elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `elem` is a *copy* of the array element, so the pointers you pass to `readf` are pointers to the temporary value.

You have two options here, you can use a pointer:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    auto elem = &somestruct_array[i];
    file_handle.readf ("%e %e %e %e %e %e\n",
        &(elem.pos_x), &(elem.pos_y),
        &(elem.pos_z), &(elem.vel_x),
        &(elem.vel_y), &(elem.vel_z));
}
```

or, you can iterate the array by reference:

```
foreach (ref elem; somestruct_array[0..1000]) {
    file_handle.readf ("%e %e %e %e %e %e\n",
        &(elem.pos_x), &(elem.pos_y),
        &(elem.pos_z), &(elem.vel_x),
        &(elem.vel_y), &(elem.vel_z));
}
```

Note that if the array is 1000 elements long, you can just write:

```
foreach (ref elem; somestruct_array)
```

Comment: AFAIK "alias elem = somestruct_array[i]" should also work, shouldn't it?

Comment: works! @МихаилСтрашун: That doesn't seem to work. Compiler says; `alias elem cannot alias an expression somestruct_array[i]`

Comment: @steffen Yes, I have checked http://dlang.org/declaration.html#AliasDeclaration and it seems it accepts only types now. Strange, I remember using it for expressions and thought it is a neat feature. Was a neat bug most likely :)

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
for (uint i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
auto elem = &somestruct_array[i];
file_handle.readf ("%e %e %e %e %e %e\n",
        &(elem->pos_x), &(elem->pos_y),
        &(elem->pos_z), &(elem->vel_x),
        &(elem->vel_y), &(elem->vel_z));
}
```

This way you're dealing with the actual array element reference, not the reference to the local auto variable.

Comment: And then I saw this question was for 'D'. I'll now wait and see if this answer is remotely correct.

Comment: Hehe... I tried that before as I guessed it from C++ as you did. It doesn't work. The compile error is `Error: expression expected, not '>'` in each line, `->` appears.